# Azure Search : Blob Metadata Field value not appearing in Indexed data

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We have set Metadata on Block Blob and are able to verify the Key/Value correctly stamped on the blob.
[image]

Out of many fields that have been defined in the index, only one field value (PromotionId) is not appearing in the indexed data, as can be confirmed by executing search through the "Search explorer".
[image]

This field has actually been mapped to the key "ID" in the indexer.
[image]

And has been defined in Index.
[image]

Why is the value of this specific field not appearing in the index? Rest all metadata fields are all appearing in the index as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field mapping is not working because "ID" is specified as a sourceFieldName, but there is no ID property on the source Blob as it only exists on the Index you have defined.

This may be a bit confusing since it behaves like there is an "ID" property because the "ID" field is being populated without a field mapping.  However, this is because Azure Search automatically maps the "metadata_storage_path" to whichever field is the document key when no field mapping for the document key is specified.  This behavior is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#defining-document-keys-and-field-mappings).

If you want the PromotionId to be the document path like the ID field you can change the sourceFieldName to "metadata_storage_path" for the PromotionId field mapping.  If you want to also be base64 encoded you can add the fieldMappingFunction to the field mapping as well.

Comment: I changed value of "sourceFieldName" from "ID" to "metadata_storage_path", and now index shows the full blob file path as value of "PromotionId". But, how do I show the value that is stamped in the metadata? If I remove the mapping, it will show the stamped value, but not sure if NOT mapping with "ID" will create any other issues.

Comment: If you want the PromotionId field on the index to map to the PromotionId field in blob the metadata then you just remove the field mapping since this is the same as haveing both the sourceFieldName and targetFieldName being set to "PromotionId".  FieldMappings are only needed if you want to map two fields with different names or apply a field mapping function (such as base64).